# Can we have Unbalanced Group along with SSRM / unbalanced group with Lazy loading on CSM

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

We have a requirement where we have a bunch of data coming from the server, but the data is not loaded in one shot and broken into API for each group .

The Data may or may not contain groups based on some condition which has to be computed. The Data in this case is a complex object where there is no direct computation of field and has to be done in renderer / valueGetter.

Is there is a way to have a AgGrid setup using CSM to have data loaded lazily and have unbalanced Rows.

Or Can we use SSRM along with unbalanced Rows for Grouping.

Data Example

```
{
  "issueCount": {
    "count": 4,
    "count1": 116,
    "count3": 88
  },
  "issues": [
    {
      "prop1": {
        "code": "USD",
        "code1": 1567.0,
        "code3": 1567.0
      },
      "[No group if 1 object]": [
        {
          "data": {
            "time": "1668944464000",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "mis": "f",
            "id": "fd",
            "type": "r",
            "name": "a"
          },
          "data1": {
            "submissionStatus": null
          }
        }
      ],
      "prop": 2,
      "prop2": {
        "id": "a",
        "title": null
      },
      "prop3": [
        {
          "assign": "ddd"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "prop1": {
        "code": "USD",
        "code1": 34.0,
        "code3": 34.0
      },
      "[group if 2 object]": [
        {
          "data": {
            "time": "1668944464000",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "mis": "f",
            "id": "fd",
            "type": "r",
            "name": "a"
          },
          "data1": {
            "submissionStatus": null
          }
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "time": "1668944464000",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "mis": "f",
            "id": "fd",
            "type": "r",
            "name": "a"
          },
          "data1": {
            "submissionStatus": null
          }
        }
      ],
      "prop": 55,
      "prop2": {
        "id": "edwd",
        "title": "Asha PARS Test Product"
      },
      "prop3": [
        {
          "assign": "eww"
        },
        {
          "assign": "ewrw"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Mid": 5,
  "pageOffset": 1,
  "pageSize": 10
}
```

[image]

Where the rows marked in teal are expandable and others not and on expanding we make a call and merge data into the row it was expanded.

The only thing remotely possible is Master grid in Aggrid is there anything else we can use

Answer (score 0):

You probably need SSRM [Tree Data](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/server-side-model-tree-data/). In tree mode, you can specify which row is expandable.

It has `isServerSideGroup` callback, where you can compute your condition. Another callback `getServerSideGroupKey` will let you derive some identificator of the group, which will be passed to datasource getRows method.